# NSImageView transparency

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimageview

I'm beginner with programming for OS X and I have problems with setting `NSImageView` transparency.

In iOS it was quite simple, there's property in `UIImageView` called `alpha` and I could change it and animate it. (like `imageView.alpha = 0.5`)

How can I achieve the same with `NSImageView`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set the property `alphaValue` of a NSView that has a layer!

```
[view setWantsLayer:YES];
[view setAlphaValue:0];
```

Comment: on osx (other than on ios), views dont have layers per default

Comment: but it might d be better not to use a layer and embedd the transparency in the image itself ... MAYBE